# Why SRWebSocket is causing app crash when app comes from background to foreground?

Tags: ios, crash, sigabrt

Hi i am using SRWebSocket to receive commands to IOS app. Here i observed one issue when ever app come from background to foreground app is crashing and giving this error.

Assertion failed: (mapped_size >= sizeof(_currentReadMaskOffset) + offset), function -[SRWebSocket _readFrameContinue]_block_invoke_2, file /Volumes/StreamTV - MaxxSouth/Stream TV/evo_ios2.0/Pods/SocketRocket/SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.m, line 1131.

Any one have any idea how to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: did you get a solution?